# $\mathscr{L}_p$ spaces exercise

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

*Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $f\in\mathscr{L}_p$ with $p\in(1,\infty)$ and $q$ its conjugate. Show that:
$\int_X|f|d\mu\leqslant\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{q}}(\int_X|f|^pd\mu)^{\frac{1}{p}}$*

I have followed a hint to use Hölder´s inequality and write $f\mathbb{1}_X$ which is the characteristic function. However I cannot get the inequality out of $\int_X|f|d\mu$? How can I get $\mu(x)^q$ out of $\int_X|f|d\mu$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is literally a direct application of Holder's inequaltiy.

Let q be the conjuate of p, i.e $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Then we have that 
$\int_{X}{|f 1_{X} dm|} \leq (\int_X{(1_{x})^q})^{1/q} ( \int_{X}{|f|^p})^{1/p}$. Then you have that $(\int_X{(1_{x})^q})^{1/q}=(\int_{X}{1_{X}})^{1/q}=m(X)^{1/q}$.

Comment: But the function needs to have a domain equal to X,right?

Comment: Or a measurable subset of X, $f \in L^{p}(m)$ which is defined on your sigma algebra of X. Note, this result is what gives you $L^p$ space containment for finite measure spaces, namely, $L^1 \subset L^2 \subset ...$

Comment: I was thinking on the same proof you presented in the answer the only thing that made doubtful was the fact: $\int_X f\:d\mu=\int f\mathbb{1}_X\:d\mu=\int f\:d\mu\int\mathbb{1}_X\:d\mu=\mu(X)\int_X f\:d\mu$ which seems contradictory.

Comment: Your second equality is false.

Comment: Which one is the second equality and Why is it wrong?

Comment: $\int_{[0,2]}{x} \neq \int_{[0,2]}{x} \int_{[0,2]}{1}$

Comment: Thank you! You have been very helpful. I got it now. I was not remembering the Hölder´s inequality.

Comment: Glad I could help.